Difference between the two version numbers from `adb --version`
I am currently a bit confused why there are two version numbers provided by adb --version:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian

My current guess is that the first one indicates the protocol/API/server version and the second one indicates the ADB implementation/client version.
I would be glad if somebody could provide some further insights.

Looking at the source code of adb sheds a little bit of light onto what the version string means:
The first line Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Shows a version that comprises of three parts:

ADB_VERSION_MAJOR = 1
ADB_VERSION_MINOR = 0
ADB_SERVER_VERSION = 41

The definition of ADB_SERVER_VERSION has the comment Increment this when we want to force users to start a new adb server. Based on own experience I know that if you execute adb it connects to the adb server running the local computer and checks this version. If adb client and server do not share the version number the adb client kills and restarts adb server.
The second line Version 28.0.2-debian is what is called ADB_VERSION in the source code. This seems to be the adb version number respectively the version of the Android SDK Platform-Tools this adb version belongs to.
On newer adb executables I have seen as a slightly second line: Version 35.0.1-11580240. 35.0.1 is the Android SDK Platform-Tools and 11580240 some sort of build number.
